# numpy dtype duplicate the array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dtype

I try to add a dtype in a numpy array (for the creation after of a ply file), but when I write this:

```py
list_example = np.array([[1,2,3]], dtype=[('example', 'i4', (3,))]
```

The result is :

```py
array([[([1, 1, 1],), ([2, 2, 2],), ([3, 3, 3],)]],
      dtype=[('example', '<i4', (3,))])
```

And i don't understand why it's duplicate every components of my array. Because if I do this:

```py
np.array([([1,2,3], 255)], dtype = [('example', 'i4', (3,)), ('color', 'u1')])
```

I obtain:

```py
array([([1, 2, 3], 255)], dtype=[('example', '<i4', (3,)), ('color', 'u1')])
```

where my array dont duplicate `[1,2,3]`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating structured arrays, the distinction between list and tuple is important.  The inputs should match the print display, as your working case shows.

For the first dtype, try:

```
In [525]: np.zeros(1, dtype=[('example', 'i4', (3,))])
Out[525]: array([([0, 0, 0],)], dtype=[('example', '<i4', (3,))])
```

imitating that:

```
In [526]: np.array([([1,2,3],)], dtype=[('example', 'i4', (3,))])
Out[526]: array([([1, 2, 3],)], dtype=[('example', '<i4', (3,))])
```

`np.array([([1,2,3])], dtype=[('example', 'i4', (3,))])` doesn't help because the () include a single list, without a comma, so they do nothing.  Your dtype has one field, so the input must have a single element tuple per record.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rec.fromarrays`

```
>>> np.rec.fromarrays([([1,2,3])], dtype=[('example', 'i4', (3,))])

rec.array(([1, 2, 3],),
          dtype=[('example', '<i4', (3,))])
```